# Strange normal map behavior in Cycles (Blender 2.80)

Tags: mesh, normals, baking

I have a problem with normal map baking from high-poly to low-poly in Cycles. When I apply the normal map on the rendered object appears quads, but in eevee this doesn't appen. The strange thing is that these quads doesn't correspond to the wireframe of the mesh visible in Edit mode.
These quads are visible in the normal map, but why they don't appear in eevee? How can I bake normals without quads?
Thank you.
 [image: With quads visble in Cycles]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure to set shading of both objects to Smooth, then rebake.

Comment: Shading of both object was already Smooth. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to save the output normal map image (with *Save As* in the Image editor). This made baking work correctly.

Comment: Looks like unexpected behaviour or a bug; probably Blender couldn't rewrite image unless it was explicitly saved as file which invoked update.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that seams to work is when you check the "32 bit float" when creating a new image to bake on. And sometimes that fixes weird artifacts but at the cost of eating a little more Vram and the color of the map being lighter (but the data should still be correct from the map)